# PSQLException thrown when trying to execute SELECT query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have problem with my SQL request, when I run my request, I receive this message error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.
```

Here is my request:

```
Connexion con = new Connexion();  

try {
  c = con.Connect();
  stmt = c.createStatement();

  int sqlCalcul = stmt.executeUpdate(
      "SELECT inventaire FROM calcul WHERE designation='" + designation + 
      "' AND date=(SELECT MAX(date) FROM calcul)");

  stmt.close();
  // c.commit();
  c.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
  System.exit(0);
}
System.out.println("Records created successfully");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `executeQuery` instead of `executeUpdate`:

```
ResultSet sqlCalcul = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT inventaire...")
```

[`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) is used for a `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement, and will throw an exception if a `ResultSet` is returned. [`executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) should be used for `SELECT` statements.

Take a look at [PostgreSQL's tutorial](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html) using the JDBC driver for more information.